How to scope autogen tool to working dir?
I am playing with AutoGen and I've added tools to read and write text files (mainly because don't want to waste resource)
My agent has working dir
executor = autogen.UserProxyAgent(
    name="executor",
    system_message="Executor. Execute the code written by the Engineer and report the result.",
    human_input_mode="NEVER",
    code_execution_config={
        "last_n_messages": 3,
        "work_dir": WORKING_DIR,
        "use_docker": False,
    },  # Please set use_docker=True if docker is available to run the generated code. Using docker is safer than running the generated code directly.
)

And tools
def read_file(file_name: Annotated[str, "File name has to be json, txt or html"]) -> int:
    if not file_name.endswith(".json") and not file_name.endswith(".txt") and not file_name.endswith(".html"):
        return f"I can read only .json, .txt or .html files you asked for {file_name}. Use python to read other files."
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(WORKING_DIR, file_name)):
        return f"File {file_name} does not exist."
    with open(os.path.join(WORKING_DIR, file_name), "r") as f:
        return f.read()


def write_file(file_name: Annotated[str, "File name"], content: Annotated[str, "text or json content"]) -> int:
    # verify that nested folders exists
    if not os.path.exists(f"{WORKING_DIR}/{os.path.dirname(file_name)}"):
        os.makedirs(f"{WORKING_DIR}/{os.path.dirname(file_name)}")

    with open(f"{WORKING_DIR}/{file_name}", "w") as f:
        return f.write(content)

How can I do it better? So I don't have to worry about working dir in my code.

You can use os.getcwd()
See here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-getcwd-method/

It will just tell me working folder from python perspective. I want to limit it to agents working folder. Will ipdate question to be more specific

Assuming your code is executed in the agents working folder.. you can use inspect.get_file()
